# Syntax error in OCaml evaluation function

Tags: ocaml

I found this code to evaluate expressions in OCaml on the internet and want to try to understand how it works, but when I enter it in my editor and run it I get the following error:

```
type t =
| Integer of int
| Binary of binary * t * t
and binary =
| Add
| Sub
| Mult
| Div

type token =
| INTEGER of int
| ADD
| SUB
| MULT
| DIV
let rec eval = function
| Integer(k) -> k
| Binary(op, a, b) ->
(match op with
| Add -> ( + )
| Sub -> ( - ) 
| Mult -> ( * )
| Div -> ( / )) (eval a) (eval b)

let lexer s =
let open Str in
let split s =
let rec splitchar x l =
if x< 0 then l else splitchar (x-1) ( s.[x]:: l ) in
splitchar ( String.length s -1) [] 
|> List.map
(function
| "+" -> ADD
| "-" -> SUB
| "*" -> MULT
| "/" -> DIV
| _ ->     failwith "lexer: Invalid token: %s" );;
```

Characters 280-282:
| _ -> failwith "lexer: Invalid token: %s" );;
                                            ^^
Error: Syntax error

The error message doesn't help very much and I've tried a few changes that only make things worse. Can anyone help me get started by figuring out what the syntax error is?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a couple of issues :

- split is defined but not used.
- failwith expects a string, not a format.

For the first issue : you have to use split before List.map:

```
...in split s | List.map...
```

failwith expect a string, in the current case, the mistake is that it is a string that looks more a format string that waits for another string.
The fix is as below :
 - first catch the string
 - then use it to form the final string expected by failwith

```
    (function
| "+" -> ADD <br>
| "-" -> SUB <br>
| "*" -> MULT <br>
| "/" -> DIV <br>
| _ as s ->     failwith ("lexer: Invalid token: " ^ s) );;
```

But I am not sure at all the whole code will work....